# Expand a differentiation-like product

Tags: algebra, ncalgebra

Suppose I have some symbols $\tau$, $a[-i]$ and $b[-j]$, where $i,j=1,\cdots,7$. The relation between them are

$$a[-i]a[-j]=a[-j]a[-i],$$
$$a[-i]b[-j]=b[-j]a[-i],$$ 
$$b[-i]b[-j]=b[-j]b[-i],$$

where $i,j=1,\cdots,7$. Also we have

$$\tau\,H[-i]-H[-i]\tau=i\,H[-i-1],\quad i=1,2,3,4,5,6.$$

Now I want to expand the following expression

\begin{align*}(\tau-2a[-1]-b[-1])&(\tau-a[-1]-2b[-1])(\tau-a[-1]+b[-1])\\ &\times\tau(\tau+a[-1]-b[-1])(\tau+a[-1]+b[-1])(\tau+2a[-1]+b[-1])\end{align*}

as a polynomial in $\tau$ so that it equals

$$\tau^7+w_2\tau^5+w_3\tau^4+w_4\tau^3+w_5\tau^2+w_6\tau+w_7.$$

Then I want the expressions for $w_i$, $i=2,3,\dots,7$, in terms of $a[-i]$ and $b[-j]$, $i,\,j=1,\cdots,7$.

Comment: Have you seen [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html)?

Comment: @aardvark2012 I just looked at it. But this is noncommutative.

Comment: Where does `H` come in to the expression you want to expand? Can you post your actual code?

Comment: @aardvark2012 H=a or b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have commutativity, you can't use `Times`. You can use [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) (`**` for short) and then use transformation rules to get to the form you want:

```
exp = 
 NonCommutativeMultiply[(τ - 2 a[-1] - b[-1]), (τ - a[-1] - 2 b[-1]), (τ - a[-1] + 
  b[-1]), τ, (τ + a[-1] - b[-1]), (τ + a[-1] + b[-1]), (τ + 2 a[-1] + b[-1])]
(* (τ - 2 a[-1] - b[-1]) ** (τ - a[-1] - 2 b[-1]) ** (τ - a[-1] + b[-1])
  ** τ ** (τ + a[-1] - b[-1]) ** (τ + a[-1] + b[-1]) ** (τ + 2 a[-1] + b[-1]) *)
```

The rules (if it is unclear how one of them works, just ask):

```
moveFacs = NonCommutativeMultiply[pre___, f_?NumericQ a_., post___] :> 
  f NonCommutativeMultiply[pre, If[a === 1, Unevaluated@Sequence[], a], post];
moveTau = τ ** (H : (a | b))[i_] :> i H[i - 1] + H[i] ** τ /; MemberQ[-Range@6, i];
collect = f1_. a1_ ** b_ + f2_. a2_ ** b_ :> (f1 a1 + f2 a2) ** b;
expand = e_ :> Expand@e;
distribute = e : _[___, Plus[_, __], ___] :> Distribute@e; 
makeCommuting[a__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[p : Alternatives[a] ..] :> Times[p]
```

We write rules for `Expand` and `Distribute` so that we can nicely chain them with the rest. Now, the actual transformation:

```
exp //. {moveFacs, moveTau, distribute}
 /. makeCommuting[τ] /. makeCommuting[a[_], b[_]] //. collect
```

The first part does most of the work: It sort numerical factors to the front and commutes `τ` to the end. `Distribute` is also applied where necessary. Afterwards, we mark `a[_]` and `b[_]` as commuting with each other (as well as `τ` with itself) and collect terms (we can't use `Collect`, since that one doesn't work for `**`). If I didn't mess up, all these rules are mathematically strictly correct, so they should be applicable to arbitrary expressions.

## Update

As requested in the comments, we can bring the resulting expression in a form where we can apply the rules again (note that I changed the definition of `moveFacs` above):

```
res = exp //. {moveFacs, moveTau, distribute} /. 
 makeCommuting[τ] /. makeCommuting[a[_], b[_]] //. collect;

ω6 = FirstCase[res, ω6_ ** τ :> ω6]

reexpand = {Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply, a_^n_ :> NonCommutativeMultiply@@Table[a, n]}

τ ** ω6 //. reexpand //. {moveFacs, moveTau, distribute} 
 /. makeCommuting[τ] /. makeCommuting[a[_], b[_]] //. collect
```

`reexpand` simply replaces every occurence of `Times` with `**` (to make everything more uniform) and replaces powers, e.g. `τ^3`⟶`τ**τ**τ`

Comment: Thank you. After getting the result of w6, I want to do the same thing again for tau ** w6. The same code get stuck when there are some powers like square and cubic. How should the code be changed? Thanks.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake when copying the code together - I'll update the answer when I figured out what's missing

Comment: @Nirvanacs: I update the answer with a way to apply the rules to the output again. Does this cover all your cases?

Comment: Great, works pefectly for me.